# How to fix 'Redirect from 'XXX' to 'YYY' has been blocked by cors policy

Tags: spring, apache, cors, spring-cloud

I have the following architecture.

I have a spring cloud gateway server which handles authentication, authorization and routing.
We can shell call him server `A`.

Another server is an authentication server `B` which uses Kerberos to authenticate users. To use it, `A` redirect a request of the form `A/a/route`, to a request of the form `B/a/route` with status `307`.

Then server `B` authenticates the user and adds a cookie with the JWT, and responds with redirect `A/a/route` with status `307`.

When server `A` gets the redirected requests with the JWT cookie he proxies it to the API server.

During this all process we get the following error

> Failed to load `A/a/route`: Redirect from `A/a/route` to `B/a/route` has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

We set all `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers to allow all requests on both servers `A` and `B` the following way

In the spring gateway server

```java
@Bean
public WebFilter corsFilter() {
    return (ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) -> {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        if (CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request)) {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Method", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT");
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", /* HEADRS */);
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            if (HttpMethod.OPTIONS.equals(request.getMethod())) {
                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
                return Mono.empty();
            }
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

In the apache-httpd Kerberos server

```
<VirtualHost *>
    LuaRoot /etc/httpd/lua
    LuaHookFixups authz.lua check_authz_cookie
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SetEnvIf Origin "(.*)" origin=$0
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{origin}e"

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Method "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers # HEADERS...

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

    ProxyPass /whoami !

    ProxyPass / A
    ProxyPassReverse / A

</VirtualHost>
```

We expect the redirects to work, but the CORS problems happen.

Answer (score 0):

The CORS policy doesn't allow multiple values in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. Try to remove the '*' and make sure only one address is set in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'